# How to get Yii parameters directly from the querystring (URL)

Tags: php, url, yii, frameworks

I am using the latest version of Yii and trying to basically collate the URL parameters.

For instance if my URL was as follows:

```
site.com/events/199/111
```

What is the function to grab the first parameter e.g '199' and similarly again to say grab the 2nd parameter e.g '111'.

I remember CodeIgniter has `$this->url->segment(1)`, I basically need the same functionality to Yii :)

Comment: May be you simple to use CodeIgniter? Yii has a UrlManager, that uses rules in config. Rule like `'events/<param1:\d+>/<param2:\d+>' => 'events/show' call EventController->actionShow($param1,$param2) {}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On somthing like -

```
$this->createUrl('blah/blahx',array('id'=>2));
```

You can get your parameter using -

```
$x = CHttpRequest::getParam('id'); //outputs x=2
```

OR  `$x = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id'); //x=2 again`

Comment: I will do have to wait a few more mins :)

Comment: I had the follwing URL i.e. http://localhost/FedSeed/reports/multi/1 and I used CHttpRequest::getParam('id'); to access the last 1 digit :)

Comment: I have similar kind of issue can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73581066/6854117)?

Answer (score 4):

you can try getParam method

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');
```

Comment: I have similar kind of issue can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73581066/6854117)?

Comment: The link is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should read this :

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action-parameter-binding

About your problem, you should simply create a corresponding url rule, e.g. :

```
'events/<param1>/<param2>'=>'events/view',
```

And then in your controller :

```
public function actionView($param1, $param2)
{
    // you can now use $param1 and $param2
}
```

Comment: my url is like this `bookings/booking/01-SEPT-2022` and I want to get the `01-SEPT-2022` part. `'extraPatterns' => [ 'POST booking/{j}-{M}-{Y}' => 'booking',
                        'POST bookingdet/{j}-{M}-{Y}' => 'bookingdet',
                    ],` . and then following your answer I have done `public function actionBooking($j,$k,$l)`  after than when I do `var_dump($k);` it says `"Missing required parameters: k, l",`

Comment: I have similar kind of issue can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73581066/6854117)?

Answer (score -1):

You just need uri component. 
Here is the solution , you can use uri component like this ; Yii::app()->uri->segment(2);

for details follow url

http://www.hasandemir.com/how-to-get-contoller-action-segments-like-codeigniter/